# getStaticProps returns undefined when exporting | NextJS

Tags: reactjs, next.js

I'm working on a blog with nextjs. I want to export it as a static website.
My problem is that I want to make a dynamic routing (for multiple posts) so I created a [post].js file under a blog page (which contains only getStaticProps but works correctly).
When building my app, everything is Ok, when running the app (`yarn next`) everything is also Ok. But when I try to `yarn export` in order to deploy the website, I get this error :

```
Error: Error serializing `.title` returned from `getStaticProps` in "/blog/[post]".
Reason: `undefined` cannot be serialized as JSON. Please use `null` or omit this value.
... etc
Error: Export encountered errors on following paths:
        /blog/[post]
```

I tried to simplify my code as much as possible. All I do is to show the message I pass on props, but even like this, it does not work. All the other components are just esthetical components, so I really don't understand what's the problem. Here's the code of [post].js:

```
const Post = props => {
    const [enableParticles, setEnableParticles] = React.useState(true);

    return (
        <div className="App">
            <Header blog />
            <Layout>
                <SocialMediaNav />
                <ParticlesNetwork enableParticles={enableParticles} />
                <ToggleButton
                    checked={enableParticles}
                    onClick={() => setEnableParticles(!enableParticles)}
                />
                <SectionWrapper id="blog-homepage" offset={0} minHeight="90vh">
                    {props.title}
                </SectionWrapper>
            </Layout>
            <Footer />
        </div>
    );
};

export async function getStaticPaths() {
    return {
        paths: [
            { params: { post: 'mes_notes_en_probabilites' } }
        ],
        fallback: false,
    };
}

export async function getStaticProps(context) {
    return {
        props: {
            title: context.params.post
        },
    };
}
export default Post;
```

note: i tried to do as it was said on this tutorial: https://dev.to/akuks/what-is-getstaticpaths-in-nextjs-5ee5

Do you have an idea?

Comment: Whatever value you're passing to `props.title` in `getStaticProps` is undefined. You should check the value first and handle it accordingly. Is that your actual code though? That code wouldn't trigger the error you're seeing.

Comment: @juliomalves I already checked the value and it does not work ! i'm actually passing directly a string .. so why would it be "undefined" ? and yes this is the actual code i'm trying to run, i made it this much simple just to test because this problem is really weird.